# Static method missing in bytecode

Tags: java

I have a simple program like below:

```
    public class StringDemo {

          public static String s = "abcdef";

          private static boolean test(String str) {
            if (!str.startsWith("abc")) {
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          } 

          public static void doTest() {
            test(s);
          }

          public static void main(String srgs[]) {
            doTest();
          }
    }
```

Both `test` and `doTest` are static methods, but after compiling to bytecode, I can only see `doTest`, and `test`is missing. Can anybody explain for me why? Thanks.

P/S: I can't put bytecode in here, because stackoverflow keeps showing an error "your post is mostly code, please put more details"...etc

Comment: If you cannot post something here, there are tools such as http://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use javap with -private flag in order to see private methods
javap -c -private xxxxxxxx